# When does the sum of parts equal to the whole?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to prove the following statements.

First, some definitions - here is my attempt to define a montonic function:

A function $f(x)$ is monotonic on an interval $I$ if for any two points $x_1, x_2 \in I$, the following conditions hold:

- Monotonically Increasing: If $x_1 < x_2$ then $f(x_1) \leq f(x_2)$
- Monotonically Decreasing: If $x_1 < x_2$ then $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$

If either of these conditions holds for all $x_1, x_2 \in I$, then $f(x)$ is said to be monotonic on $I$. If neither condition holds, then $f(x)$ is not monotonic.

**Statements to Prove**

1. Define a function $TV_n(f) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})|$  where $x_i = a + i \frac{b-a}{n}$ for $i = 0, 1, ..., n$

As the number of divisions $n$ goes to infinity, then:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} TV_n(f) = TV(f)$$

2. Define a function $QV_n(f) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1}))^2$ where $x_i = a + i \frac{b-a}{n}$ for $i = 0, 1, ..., n$.

As the number of divisions $n$ goes to infinity:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} QV_n(f) = 0$$

**I am trying to understand why these statements are always true for monotonic functions and not always true for non-monotonic functions.**

I am not sure how to mathematically prove both these statements are always true for monotonic functions and not always true for non-monotonic functions.

For the non-monotonic functions, I was trying to find a function to serve as a counterexample to disprove this. But I was hoping to learn how to write a mathematical proof for these.

I wrote some R code to calculate TV and QV for a specific function over a specific interval with a specific number of partitions:

```
f <- function(f, a, b, n) {
    x <- seq(a, b, length.out = n+1)
        fx <- sapply(x, f)
    
    diffs <- diff(fx)
    
    TV <- sum(abs(diffs))
    
    QV <- sum(diffs^2)
    
    return(list(TV = TV, QV = QV))
}

#  example:
f <- function(x) { x^2 }
a <- 0
b <- 2
n <- 10000
variations <- calculate_variations(f, a, b, n)
print(variations)
```

I can see that for this specific monotonic function, QV reaches closer to 0 for larger numbers of partitions whereas the value of TV stays the same:

```
$TV
[1] 4

$QV
[1] 0.002133333
```

But how can I learn to write a mathematical proof for this?

Comment: What is the definition of $TV(f)$?

Answer (score 1):

For the first statement, the only thing you need to note is that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vert f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})\vert = \left\vert\sum_{i=1}^{n} (f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}))\right\vert$$
holds for monotonic function $f$.

For the second statement, I think you need some extra condition like continuity, because we have following counterexample:

Let $a=0$, $b=1$ and take an arbitrary irrational number $r\in [0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$,
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x,  & x<r\\
x+10, & x\geqslant r
\end{cases}$$
Now, there \exists $i$ such that $r\in (\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n})$ and
$$QV_n(f) \geqslant (f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}))^2 \geqslant 10^2$$
for all $n$, which means the second statement fails.